# Timezone updater doesn't work

Tags: java, timezone

This 26th of October new timezone was set(-1 hour). So I ran this command on 24th:

```
java -jar tzupdater.jar --update
```

And now(10:19) time doesn't work with new timezone:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date d = new Date();
        System.out.println(d);

    }
```

Output:

> Mon Oct 27 11:19:35 MSK 2014

I tried to run that command again:

> You have the same version as the embedded one

Versions are:

> tzupdater version 1.4.8-b01 JRE time zone data version: tzdata2014h
>   Embedded time zone data version: tzdata2014h

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be sure which jre you expect to be updated. It can be more than one jre on your host. In my windows i have at least two jre-s: in /Program Files/jdk/jre and in /Program Files/jre folders.
You have to check ALL jre/lib folders. The folder jre_home/lib/zi should be updated (notice the folder time). 
I don't know how updater choose the jre_home but i know that it doesn't always update the jre-s you expect.
In Windows you seems can just put updated zi folder to jre_home/lib, but in Unix i'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to understand what a timezone is, and what this command does.

A Timezone is not an hour offset. A TimeZone is something like "Europe/Paris". And a TimeZone encapsulates the offset, along with the rules that govern the changes to the offset. For example, if you use the timezone "Europe/Paris", then you'll be at UTC+2 in the summer time, and at UTC+1 in the winter time. The TimeZone knows the rules and knows when to go from summer to winter time.

Since these rules frequently change, you can update them thanks to the command you executed. So, the command doesn't change the offset from UTC+2 to UTC+1. It simply updates your Java installation so thet new rules, that have been introduced since the last update, are taken into account.